# Media query help, are these the right ones am using?

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

On the current RWD website am building, the media query used for mobile(iphone)/tab(ipad)/laptop screens(1366X768 px) are:

```
/*  #Mobile (Portrait) 320px
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 479px)

/* #Mobile (Landscape)
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)

/* #Tablet (Portrait)
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)

/* #Tablet (Landscape)
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media all and (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1920px)

/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) and larger devices */
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px) and (max-width: 1177px)

/* Desktops and laptops (laptop browser version styles) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) and (max-width: 1366px)
```

Are these the right ones am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , also include these for a perfect RWD

```
// Little larger screen
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

}

// Pads and larger phones
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

}

// Larger pads
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}

// Horizontal pads and laptops
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

}

// Really large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 1382px) {

}

// 2X size (iPhone 4 etc)
@media only screen and 
        (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and 
        (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and 
        (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
```

}
If you use Sass, here's a little trick I've been using:

```
$laptop-size: "only screen and (min-width: 768px)";
$desktop-size: "only screen and (min-width: 1382px)";
```

// etc
And then

```
@media #{$laptop-size} {
    // Styling here...
}
```

Comment: if it is helpfull please tick the answer :)